# How to shift Index of Series by 1 row in another pandas TimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, series

I have a pd.DatetimeIndex named "raw_Ix" which contains all the indices i am working with and two pandas (Time)series("t1" and "nextloc_ixS") (both with the same timeindex).
the values in "nextloc_ixS" are the same indices of t1.index and nextloc_ixS.index Shifted by one in raw_Ix. to better understand what "nextloc_ixS" is:

```
   nextloc_ixS =  t1.index[np.searchsorted(raw_Ix, t1.index)+1]
   nextloc_ixS = pd.DataFrame(nextloc_ixS, index = t1.index)
```

All three get passed into a function, where i need them in the following form:

1. I need to drop the t1-rows where t1.index is not in raw_Ix (to avoid errors, since raw_Ix could have been manipulated)
2. After that I now copy t1 deeply (lets call it t1_copy). because I need the **Values** of nextloc_ixS as the new DatetimeIndex of t1_copy. (sounds simple, but here i got difficulties)
3. But before I replace the index of i might need to save the old index of t1_copy as a column in t1_copy, for the last step (== step 5).
4. The actual function selects some indices of t1_copy in a specific procedure and returns "result", which is a pd.DatetimeIndex that containes some indices **of t1_copy with duplicates**
5. i need to shift result back by 1, but **not** via np.searchsorted. (note: "result" is still artificially shifted forward, so we can set it backwards by getting the indices location in t1_copy.index and then in the backup column from step 3 getting the "old"-indices.

I know it sounds a bit complicated, therefore here is the inefficient code which i worked on:

```
def main(raw_Ix, t1, nextloc, nextloc_ixS=None):   

    t1_copy = t1.copy(deep=True).to_frame()
    nextloc_ixS = nextloc_ixS.to_frame() 
    
    if nextloc_ixS is not None: 
         
        t1_copy                  = t1_copy.loc[t1_copy.index.intersection(pd.DatetimeIndex(raw_Ix))] 
        t1_copy                  = t1_copy[~t1_copy.index.duplicated(keep='first')]# somehow duplicates came up, I couldnt explain why
        t1_copy["index_old"] = t1_copy.index.copy(deep=True) 
        temp                     = nextloc_ixS.loc[nextloc_ixS.index.intersection(raw_Ix)].copy(deep=True) 
        t1_copy.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(temp[~temp.index.duplicated(keep='first')].values), inplace=True) # somehow duplicates came up, I couldnt explain why therefore the .duplicated(...)


else: # in this case we just should find the intersection
        t1_copy = t1_copy.loc[t1.index.intersection(pd.DatetimeIndex(raw_Ix))]
        t1_copy = t1_copy[~t1_copy.index.duplicated(keep='first')]  

result = func(t1_copy, raw_Ix) # this function is a huge nested algorithm. For relevance one can get random indices from t1_copy with duplicates (result has the same length as t1_copy, but random chosen indices with multiple duplicates)

if nextloc:
   # this is just "pseudo" code.
   result_locations = t1_copy.index.where(result)
   result = t1_copy["index_old"].iloc[result_locations]
```

So in a nutshell:
I try to do an index shift back and later again forth while avoiding np.searchsorted() and instead using the two pd.Series (or better call it columns because they get passed seperately from a DataFrame)

Is there any way to do that efficiently in terms of codelines and timeuse? (very large amount of rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is complex to achieve two things

1. remove rows that are not in a list.  I've used a trick for this so I can use `dropna()`
2. to `shift()` a column

This is performing pretty well. A fraction of a second on a dataset > 0.5m rows.

```
import time
d = [d for d in pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2015,5,1,2), 
                          dt.datetime(2020,5,1,4), freq="128s") 
     if random.randint(0,3) < 2 ] # miss some sample times... 

# random manipulation of rawIdx so there are some rows where ts is not in rawIdx
df = pd.DataFrame({"ts":d, "rawIdx":[x if random.randint(0,3)<=2 
                                     else x + pd.Timedelta(1, unit="s") for x in d], 
                   "val":[random.randint(0,50) for x in d]}).set_index("ts")
start = time.time()
print(f"size before: {len(df)}")
dfc = df.assign(
    # make it float64 so can have nan, map False to nan so can dropna() rows that are not in rawIdx
    issue=lambda dfa: np.array(np.where(dfa.index.isin(dfa["rawIdx"]),True, np.nan), dtype="float64"),
).dropna().drop(columns="issue").assign(
    # this should be just a straight forward shift.  rawIdx will be same as index due to dropna()
    nextloc_ixS=df.rawIdx.shift(-1)
)

print(f"size after: {len(dfc)}\ntime: {time.time()-start:.2f}s\n\n{dfc.head().to_string()}")
```

**output**

```
size before: 616264
size after: 462207
time: 0.13s

                                 rawIdx  val         nextloc_ixS
ts                                                              
2015-05-01 02:02:08 2015-05-01 02:02:08   33 2015-05-01 02:06:24
2015-05-01 02:06:24 2015-05-01 02:06:24   40 2015-05-01 02:08:33
2015-05-01 02:10:40 2015-05-01 02:10:40   15 2015-05-01 02:12:48
2015-05-01 02:12:48 2015-05-01 02:12:48   45 2015-05-01 02:17:04
2015-05-01 02:17:04 2015-05-01 02:17:04   14 2015-05-01 02:21:21
```